# How can I avoid to call properties file and properties of it every time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I wrote below spring boot application with args.

```
java jar ... --credential="path\credentials.properties"
```

Run like that from console. I get the properties file path from console and all time when I need a property, firstly I load properties file and later get my property with my key. How can I avoid it? I just want to load properties file one time and later always I want to use this first loaded file. I don't want to load again and again. Like that, I don't want to call properties of it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
class ProRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
AnalyzeManager analyzeManager;

@Autowired
AuthService authService;

@Autowired
WriterService writerService;

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProRunner.class, args);        
}

@Override
void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    try {
        String token = authService.postEntity("url", args).token;
        Map dataSet = analyzeManager.bulkCreate(args);
        writerService.write(args, dataSet)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

In every service (authService, analyzeManager, writerService), I load properties according to args. Later go on with my process.

To load properties, I create a Util method and I call it every time.

```
public class Utils {
    public static Properties getProperties(String...args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        properties.load(in);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Properties file contains things like that:

```
- username
- password
- outputFileName
- startDate
- endDate
...
```

Comment: why cant you use spring`s propertyplace holder [Sample](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example)

Comment: @Barath , properties file is not constant. It is taken from console as argument.

Comment: once property file is passed as an argument, properties are immutable. you can use property place holder and it loads the properties directly into spring`s Environment. you can just let spring to do its magic.

Comment: @Barath, Please give me some implementation on  my example. Like, we have username and startDate on our custom properties. How can we integrate it spring properties for this example?

Comment: `Utils` should be a Spring managed bean, where the Properties are loaded once during app initialization.  Also, consider adding `getUserName()`, `getPassword()` etc, to hide/encapsulate the property keys and not expose the Properties object.  And based on your description `Utils` should be named something like `CredentialsProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

You can register properties file as SpringBoot propserties source

```
@PropertySource("${credential}")
```

and `credential` variable (path to your properties file) will be read from command line arguments. Then you can use @Value annotation like this:

```
@Value("${property_name}") String property;
```

Comment: this can be an other solution but to implement it, PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is needed. Because ${credential} placeholder could not be found. The other problem is credential is not system property so you should set it as system property.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
class ProRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
AnalyzeManager analyzeManager;

@Autowired
AuthService authService;

@Autowired
WriterService writerService;

    static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.additional-location","credential from args");
        SpringApplication.run(ProRunner.class, args);        
}

@Override
void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    try {
        String token = authService.postEntity("url").token;
        Map dataSet = analyzeManager.bulkCreate();
        writerService.write(dataSet)
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Added new configuration file like below:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigProperties {

    @Value("${cred.username}")
    private String userName;
    @Value("${cred.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${date.startDate}")
    private String startDate;
    @Value("{team.id}")
    private String teamId;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public String getTeamId() {
        return teamId;
    }
}
```

And later to call properties from other class:

```
@Autowired
private ConfigProperties configProperties;
```

And call property like that:

```
configProperties.getUserName();
```

Thank you very much for your helps @Barath, @Andrew S